# SQL Server transaction log storage on AWS Disk type

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server

We are moving our SQL Server to an Amazon EC2 instance.

Of the various disk types under consideration (gp2, io1, st1), it is unclear to me which type of drive to store the transaction logs on.

I presume that the logs are written sequentially, so perhaps counter intuitively the st1 drive with its higher throughput/price might be the correct choice compared to the more advanced ssd type drives.

However, if this is not the case, between io1 and gp2 it is not clear which is the correct choice because of the burst ability of gp2.

Is there some best practice for sql server transaction logs?

Comment: Writes to the transaction log file are indeed sequential, but per database. If you have multiple databases, odds are you're going to be writing to them all at the same time, randomly. That means if you put several databases on the same server, with their log files on the same EBS volume, then the writes on that volume will be random, not sequential.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great point to consider in choice, or at least design around.